# JavaScript regex not matching but does when using online editor- variable issue?

Tags: javascript, regex

I assume it has something to do with using a variable, when I test it online I don't use a variable and it works. I haven't used much regex so I could just be doing something silly too.

```
let home = 'testhome';
let currentHome = 'testhome (8)';
let re = new RegExp(home + ' \(\d+\)');

if (currentHome.match(re)) {
    //no match
} else {
    // this is the code executed
}
```

Any help appreciated. There could be multiple numbers in the brackets of `currentHome`.

Comment: `let re = new RegExp(home + ' \\(\\d+\\)');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using RegExp constructor you should escape the escape character itself in order to form a correct reg expression.

`let re = new RegExp(home + ' \\(\\d+\\)');`

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Comment: @user3238415 welcome :)